# Extracting a substring from a string using `Regexp.new`

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this:

```
var = "Renewal Quote RQ00041233 (Payment Pending) Policy R38A014294-1"
```

I have to extract `"Payment Pending"` from that string using only the information included in another single string.

The following:

```
var[/\((.*)\)/, 1]
```

will extract what I want. I can include the string representation of the regex in the string to be given, and construct the regular expression from it using `Regexp.new`, but I have no way to achieve the information `1` used as the second argument of `[]`.

Without the second argument `1`,

```
regex_string = '\((.*)\)'
var[Regexp.new(regex_string)]
```

fetches the string `"(Payment Pending)"`instead of the expected `"Payment Pending"`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Will `var[Regexp.new('\((.*)\)'), 1]` not work?

Comment: I'd ask why you're having to pass regexes around as strings.

Comment: @sawa It will work, but I am asking Don't I have the way to convert the entire `/\((.*)\)/, 1` into a regular expression?

Comment: @Schwern Because I have to read the regular expression from the sheet and use it in my program.

Comment: @sawa I have to write the regular expression into a single cell in Excel which I need to read and use it in my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can get rid of capturing groups using a different regex:

```
var[/(?<=\().*(?=\))/]
# => "Payment Pending"
```

or

```
var[Regexp.new('(?<=\().*(?=\))')]
# => "Payment Pending"
```

Answer (score 1):

`/\((.*)\)/` is just shorthand for `Regexp.new('\((.*)\)')`.

[`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) takes a regex and a capture group as two separate arguments. `var[/\((.*)\)/, 1]` is `var[Regex, 1]`.

The important thing to realize is `1` is passed to `var[]`, not the regex.

```
re = Regexp.new('\((.*)\)')
match = var[re, 1]
```

Note: you might want to require a named capture group rather than a numbered one. It's very easy to accidentally include an extra capture group in a regex.

Comment: You might want to add the conclusion of you argument. Perhaps: "so, it is impossible to do that" or "so, it does not make sense to try to do that."

Comment: yes, I am aware of that but I have to read the regular expression as a single string from the excel sheet and use it in my program, My program receives the argument inside `Regex["]`

Comment: @Schwern It is impossible/does not make sense to include the `1` information in the regex. Wasn't that your point?

Comment: @sawa I'd assumed it was a requirement that the list of regexes has to include a capture group.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Can you require that the regexes include a capture group?

Comment: I said I have written this regexp `var[/\((.*)\)/, 1]` to find out what I am expecting but I have to pass the argument to Regex.new[''] to extract the expected string, so sawa answer perfectly fits for me.

Comment: I thinks it's instructive to show how it's done both with lookarounds (@sawa) and with a capture group (you), regardless of the wording of the question, as that choice is often available for these types of problems. A nitpik: I would say `1`, together with `:[]`, are passed (sent) to `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no nested parenthesis in the string, one way to do that without using a regular expression is as follows.

```
instance_eval "var[(i=var.index('(')+1)..var.index(')',i)-1]"
  #=> "Payment Pending"
```

See [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index), particularly the reference to the optional second argument, "offset".

Comment: Your answer is educational, but you seem to be missing the point. The issue is to express the entire instruction in a single string.

Comment: @sawa, yes, I know.

Comment: Thank you. Another way, yes. But it has to be one single expression.